Removing armatures in Blenderpy while preserving position
I am running a distributed rendering pipeline to generate some data for model training, using BlenderProc/Blenderpy and data from Objaverse. This pipeline includes normalizing objects to fit in a unit cube at the origin, and I randomly stumbled on this asset which exhibited strange rendering behavior:

When going through the validation report for this asset I noticed the following:

NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT    Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/27


NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT    Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/41

I am not at all familiar with blender so I don't really know what's going on, but it's clear the normalization is not able to transform objects associated to bones.
This is how I load the objects:
for obj in objects:
    obj_path = os.path.join(data_path, "glbs", obj["github_id"], f"{obj['objaverse_id']}.glb")
    blender_objs = bproc.loader.load_obj(obj_path)

    # Merge meshes into a single object
    merged_obj = create_with_empty_mesh(obj['objaverse_id'])
    merged_obj.join_with_other_objects(blender_objs)
    normalize_obj(merged_obj)

    merged_obj.hide(True)
    merged_obj.set_shading_mode('auto')
    loaded[obj["objaverse_id"]] = merged_obj

This is how I do the normalization:
def normalize_obj(obj: bproc.types.MeshObject):
    bbox = obj.get_bound_box()
    min_corner, max_corner = bbox[0], bbox[6]

    center = (min_corner + max_corner) / 2
    length = np.max(max_corner - min_corner)

    if length > 0:
        scale = 1 / length
    else:
        logging.error(f"Scale factor for {obj.blender_obj.name} is 0.")
        scale = 1

    obj.set_location(obj.get_location() - center)
    obj.persist_transformation_into_mesh()
    obj.set_scale(obj.get_scale() * scale)
    obj.persist_transformation_into_mesh() 

My question is thus, how would one transform this asset to get rid of armatures while keeping the ears in the correct position when transforming the object?
I have attempted removing all armatures to no avail with:
for armature in bpy.data.armatures:
    bpy.data.armatures.remove(armature, do_unlink=True)

I also wasn't able to do so by applying the armature modifiers before removing them:
def apply_armatures(obj):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    armature_modifiers = [mod for mod in obj.modifiers if mod.type == 'ARMATURE']
    if not armature_modifiers:
        print(f"No armature modifier found on {obj.name}.")
        return None

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()
    bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR_KEEP_TRANSFORM')

    for mod in armature_modifiers:
        obj.modifiers.remove(mod)

